# Kafka listening, even when AWS SecGrp is turned off

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka

We're seeing a really strange issue here. We have Kafka running on AWS, with the producer instance talking to these Kafka instances, all within the same VPC.

To simulate a Kafka-down scenario, we removed the entry in the Kafka instances' AWS SecGrp for 9092-9093 ports incoming from the producer's SecGrp. In other words, the producer should ideally NOT be able to talk to Kafka anymore. But, here's the strange part: Kafka continues to ingest data from the producer for another couple of minutes even after this.

There HAS to be something more to this than meets the eye! Can someone enlighten me, please?

Comment: I think this delay might be happening due to the secgrp rule getting applied and caching

Comment: So, if I try to telnet from the producer instance to one of the Kafka broker instances after removing the SecGrp rule, I see that the port is almost immediately blocked. But, even with this blocked port, I see Kafka ingesting data (that I'm manually sending well after closing the port) for a while!

Comment: Not surprising, remembering that security groups are stateful, and the connection is already established.  Have you tried blocking it using the (stateless) VPC Network ACL?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is an existing, open connection that is persisting for a few minutes.

You should be able to run something on either end to let you know what's happening with open connections - probably netstat would help.